# phpmyadmin,mysql - Token Mismatch but i successfully created a table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am doing a table with a foreign key, here it is.
`create table PM_Team_Members
(
PM_Team_Members_ID int NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
PM_Team_Members_firstName varchar(50) not null,
PM_Team_Members_middleName varchar(50) not null,
PM_Team_Members_lastName varchar(50) not null,
PM_Team_Members_address varchar(255) not null,
PM_Team_Members_contact numeric not null,
PM_Spec_id int,
constraint fk_PM_id foreign key (PM_Spec_id) references PM_Specialization(PM_Spec_id)
)`

and this is the reference table 
`create table PM_Specialization
(
PM_Spec_ID int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
PM_Spec_Specialization varchar(50) not null,
PM_Spec_Description varchar(255) not null
)`

When I click GO for the query. It said that `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.2162 sec)` which I assume that it go correct. But then a pop-up show that Error: Token Mismatch

How is that? Did I do something wrong or is it some kind of a bug?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't have any association to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part `references PM_Specialization(PM_Spec_id) )`

You have PM_Spec_ID not PM_Spec_id in your PM_Specialization table.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your concern. But my curiosity is killing me with "why".

Comment: I updated my answer. Have you checked your code to make sure it is in the right database? You didn't specify whether or not.

Comment: I found the reason, Zane.

Comment: I always thought that SQL isn't case sensitive. Nevertheless, Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. :) I sometimes miss that when proofreading my code for my mistakes like that so I didn't see it earlier.